# Sequelize returns wrong format from JSONB field

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

My "Item" model has a JSONB column named "formula".
I want to get it either as Object or JSON string. But what it returns is a string without quoted keys that can't be parsed as JSON.

My code:

```js
async function itemsRead (where) {
  const items = await models.item.findAll({
    where
  })
  console.log(items)
  return items
}
```

And what I see and get is:

```
[
  item {
    dataValues: {
      id: 123,
      formula: '{a:-0.81, x:5.12}',
    }
  },
.
.
.
]
```

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was in insert (create) phase. I had to pass the original formula object (and not JSON stringified or other string forms) to `create()`

```
let formula = {a:-0.81, x:5.12}
models.item.create({id:123, formula})
```